# Passing the Data from one to other in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have two HTML pages: firstpage.html and secondpage.html. In firstpage.html, there is a form-
firstpage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Filling</title>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="secondpage.html" method="GET">
Enter Serial Number: <input type="number" name="serialNumber" />
                     <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The firstpage data is sent to secondpage.html. I want to display and use the form data serialNumber in secondpage.html-
secondpage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
     <title>Display</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="selva" action="thirdpage.html">
  <input type="hidden" name="kumar">
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var locate=window.location;
    document.selva.kumar.value=locate;
    var text=document.selva.kumar.value;
      function pass(str) 
      {
        point=str.lastIndexOf('=');
        return(str.substring(point+1,str.length));
      }
document.write("Serial Number" + pass(text));
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

So now I can pass the serialNumber variable from firstpage.html to secondpage.html so that the above code in secondpage.html will show the serial nuimber, and I want same serial number in at thirdpage- 
thirdpage.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
   <title>Repeating</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="link">
    Enter Serial Number2: <input type="number" name="burns" />
                         <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

please tell how to print a data in all those pages?

Comment: Are you try with local storage?

Comment: no,can you say how to use local storage

Comment: [See the basic and usage of localstorage](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp)

Comment: If you only want to use HTML, then you could pass the value around using GET requests. If you are going to use php on your webpage, then session variables cold store this value for you

Comment: why using local storage? for simple data.  where you want to display the serial number in the second page?

Comment: [using php post method](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp)

Comment: Do the same thing you are doing from the first page to the second: change your second page form to `method="GET"` and on the third page retrieve the value the same way.

Comment: cookies are best, see usage in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14573223/set-cookie-and-get-cookie-with-javascript , if HTML5 in use, try to use local storage

Comment: localStorage is the best answer for that.

Comment: try using cookies

Answer (score -2):

The simplest method I could find for this is, write all the three pages in a single html file and display them based on conditions. This way you dont need to use localstorage.

Other method will be to use query parameters. You can simply learn how to use them. Here's the link to simple javascript-handled query params plugin:

http://jillix.github.io/url.js/

You can pass the serial no as a query parameter to another html. If you are confused on how to use this method, let me know and I'll tell you in detail.